# How do I change priority of two different implementations of hook_node_access()?

Tags: hooks

I am using the *Node View Permissions* module, which implements `hook_node_access()`. I am also using a custom module (mymodule.module) which is implementing the same hook. `node_view_permissions_node_access()` is always invoked after `mymodule_node_access()`.

How can I change the hook invocation order? `mymodule_node_access()` should be executed after `node_view_permissions_node_access()`.

Answer (score 5):

Use [`hook_module_implements_alter()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_module_implements_alter/7.x):

> This hook is invoked during module_implements(). A module may implement this hook in order to reorder the implementing modules, which are otherwise ordered by the module's system weight.

Example:

```
function MYMODULE_module_implements_alter(&$implementations, $hook) {
  if ($hook == 'node_access') {
    // Move your module's implementation to the end of the list
    $group = $implementations['MYMODULE'];
    unset($implementations['MYMODULE']);
    $implementations['MYMODULE'] = $group;
  }
}
```

In the possible event that another module also implements `hook_module_implements_alter` to move its own implementation of `hook_node_access` to the end of the list, you can get cunning and make sure your implementation of the alter hook runs last too:

```
  if ($hook == 'node_access' || $hook == 'module_implements_alter') {
    // Move your module's implementation to the end of the list
    $group = $implementations['MYMODULE'];
    unset($implementations['MYMODULE']);
    $implementations['MYMODULE'] = $group;
  }
```